# css div positioning with float

Tags: html, css

I have a div container of width and height 420px inside that container i have 4 small div's with width 140px and height 140px but 2nd divs height is 170px.if i apply css float property float:left to all the divs except container div.
Q1).where will the 4th div sit.
Q2).if i want the 4th div to come below 1st div how can i do it without using position:absolute or relative.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="section1"></div>
  <div class="section2"></div>
  <div class="section3" ></div>
  <div class="section4"></div>
</div>
```

***css***

```
.container{width:420px;height:420px;border:1px solid black;}
.section1{width:140px;height:140px;background-color:green;float:left;}
.section2{width:140px;height:170px;background-color:yellow;float:left;}
.section3{width:140px;height:140px;background-color:red;float:left;}
.section4{width:140px;height:140px;background-color:orange;float:left;}
```

[Here is the link for my code JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8kyed4fx/)

Comment: Keep one thing in mind, if you are using float then you have to use clear:both so it will remove the empty/left space and div will be maintain or else they will forced to be misplaced. but if you want 4th div in next row then use clear:both so it will remove all space and put that div in next line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your `.section4{clear:left;}`

**Demo**

```css
.container{width:420px;height:420px;border:1px solid black;}
.section1{width:140px;height:140px;background-color:green;float:left;}
.section2{width:140px;height:170px;background-color:yellow;float:left;}
.section3{width:140px;height:140px;background-color:red;float:left;}
.section4{width:140px;height:140px;background-color:orange;float:left;}


.section4{clear:left;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="section1"></div>
  <div class="section2"></div>
  <div class="section3" ></div>
  <div class="section4"></div>
</div>
```

**2nd option** your can try to `display:inline-block` as like this

```css
.container{width:420px;height:420px;border:1px solid black;font-size:0;}
    .section1{width:140px;height:140px;background-color:green;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;font-size:12px;}
    .section2{width:140px;height:170px;background-color:yellow;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;font-size:12px;}
    .section3{width:140px;height:140px;background-color:red;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;font-size:12px;}
    .section4{width:140px;height:140px;background-color:orange;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;font-size:12px;}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
      <div class="section1"></div>
      <div class="section2"></div>
      <div class="section3" ></div>
      <div class="section4"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `clear: both` to your 4th div:

https://jsfiddle.net/8kyed4fx/1/